# wordpress function files, how to loop require_once?

Tags: wordpress, loops, foreach, include, require-once

i am trying to loop through some require_once statements in wordpress functions.php file which look like this

```
// Initial theme setup
require_once locate_template('/inc/init.php');

// Register widget areas
require_once locate_template('/inc/sidebar.php');

...
```

why the following loop is not working?

```
$theme_includes = array(
  '/inc/init.php', // Initial theme setup
  '/inc/sidebar.php', // Register widget areas
  '/inc/scripts.php', // Register scripts and stylesheets
  '/inc/nav.php', // Main navigation
  '/inc/cleanup.php', // Cleanup
  '/inc/customizer.php',
  '/inc/template-tags.php', // Custom template tags
  '/inc/extras.php', // No theme functions
  '/inc/analytics.php' // Google Analytics
 );

foreach ( $theme_includes as $include ) {
  require_once locate_template( $include );
}
```

i get no error message but the files do not load

Comment: What happens if you add **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** before the relative paths?

Comment: i found the solution.. instead of `locate_template` i use `get_template_directory()`, but still don't know why the first version  is not working

Answer (score 0):

If you check [the Wordpress codex of locate_template()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/locate_template) you will find the function takes 3 parameters:

```
locate_template( $template_names, $load, $require_once )
```

1. `$template_names`: should be an array of files/templates to search 
   for
2. `$load`: boolean, if set to true will load the file(s) when found
3. `$require_once`: boolean, if set to true will load the file(s) using the require_once php function

So in this case you can forget about the foreach and just pass the array as the first parameter and set the other two params to true:

```
$theme_includes = array(
      '/inc/init.php', // Initial theme setup
      '/inc/sidebar.php', // Register widget areas
      '/inc/scripts.php', // Register scripts and stylesheets
      '/inc/nav.php', // Main navigation
      '/inc/cleanup.php', // Cleanup
      '/inc/customizer.php',
      '/inc/template-tags.php', // Custom template tags
      '/inc/extras.php', // No theme functions
      '/inc/analytics.php' // Google Analytics
);

locate_template( $theme_includes, true, true );
```